# Reveal next Input after clicked first one (FORM)

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic

I got a form which looks like this:

[image: Form Layout]

I want to reveal the next input row only if the user clicked already a input in the previous row.
for this i wrote my script but its not focusing the input directly.
so if you click slightly outside the input field the next row is still revealed.

unfortunately if i simply change the class on the click listener to the input tag its not working anymore - like its not finding the next row.

Any dynamic Solution for that before i hardcode classes for each element?

**NOTE:** (Couldnt set up codepen since its a cms and didnt knew how to import all the merged css/js and librarys to codepen)

```js
function revealNextRow() {
  $('.radio-toolbar').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next('.radio-toolbar').fadeIn();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML STRUCTURE for each input row

<form>
  <h3 class="text-center">HEADING </h3>
  <div class="radio-toolbar pb-4">
    <div class="row mt-4 mb-4">
      <div class="col-6 mb-1">
        <input type="radio" id="step1ja" name="step1" value="25" class="calc">
        <label for="step1ja" class="w-100">Ja</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 mb-1">
        <input type="radio" id="step1nein" name="step1" value="0" class="calc">
        <label for="step1nein" class="w-100">Nein</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-toolbar mt-5 pb-4 hidden">
    <h3 class="text-center">Wie wohnen Sie?</h3>
    <div class="row mt-4 mb-4">
      <div class="col-sm-4 mb-1">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the function. You need to have the event listener from the start

```js
$(function() { // on page load
  $('.radio-toolbar').on('click', 'input[type=radio]', function() {
    $(this).closest('.radio-toolbar').next().fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form>
  <h3 class="text-center">HEADING </h3>
  <div class="radio-toolbar pb-4">
    <div class="row mt-4 mb-4">
      <div class="col-6 mb-1">
        <input type="radio" id="step1ja" name="step1" value="25" class="calc">
        <label for="step1ja" class="w-100">Ja</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 mb-1">
        <input type="radio" id="step1nein" name="step1" value="0" class="calc">
        <label for="step1nein" class="w-100">Nein</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-toolbar mt-5 pb-4 hidden">
    <h3 class="text-center">Wie wohnen Sie?</h3>
    <div class="row mt-4 mb-4">
      <div class="col-6 mb-1">
        <input type="radio" id="step1ja" name="step1" value="25" class="calc">
        <label for="step1ja" class="w-100">Irgenwo</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 mb-1">
        <input type="radio" id="step1nein" name="step1" value="0" class="calc">
        <label for="step1nein" class="w-100">Nirgendwo</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks so much mplungjan!
It solved the case. i had the function implemented in "document ready" so it was loaded straigth away. - this line: .on('click', 'input[type=radio]',  solved my suffer <3